# sending mail to gmail with an php script

Tags: php, email, xampp

1.using XAMPP and localhost i am trying to send mail to gmil from a php script.
2.after trying all the changes to the files php.ini and sendmail.ini as seen in posts and other resources i can't receive mail from my following php line of code:

```
    <?php
    mail('satanower1@gmail.com','hello this is a test','From: satanower1@gmail.com');
    echo 'mail has been sent successfully.';
    ?>
```

i get back the echo statement but with no email at my inbox.
changes i tried to the sendmail.ini
file:smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com from the xampp defoult
smtp_port=465  (i tried other ports too as 25 etc..)

changes i tried to the php.ini file:
 SMTP = smtp.gmail.com and smtp_port = 465

any help available?

Comment: First try this simple script: `if(mail('your@emailaddress.com', 'Test Subject', "Test message")) echo "sent"; else echo "not sent";` If it doesn;t work, check your error logs.

Comment: Have you configured smtp authentication, are you sending from an email address attached to your account.

Comment: Your `echo` statement will get executed every time. Add an `if` check echo the message *only* if the mail was sent successfully. Also, as @Suyesh told above, it'd be wise to check the error logs to see what's wrong.

Comment: hi. thank's for the fast replay

Comment: i have tried the script you suggested at (1) and got the echo of sent

Comment: any idea what can i do to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable SMTP access in GMAIL, also you need to allow unsecure clients:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps https://support.google.com/mail/answer/75726

sendmail config

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username==*****@gmail.com
auth_password=*********
force_sender=*****@gmail.com
```

php config

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = *****@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```